# This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context

Tags: model-view-controller, secure-context

This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar.
[my signup code is not working because of this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaQCc.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is a warning not an error, probably letting you know that the website does not use https and is not as safe as it could and should be. My guess is this is not the issue with your signup code.

For future reference you're going to want to add more information when asking a question too.